# Return false; statement doesn't "return"

Tags: java, recursion, return

My return false statement doesn't work as expected. I have a recursive method called "prosegui", it works with most of the words i want to work with, but with a few of them the return false doesn't return the value "false" as it should but continue and end up returning true.

```
if (contChar < this.parola.length() - 1) {
    if (this.parola.charAt(contChar+1)==matrice[i][j])
    {
        prosegui(proseguiI,proseguiJ,i,j,contChar+1);
    } 
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("FALSE");
        return false;
    }
}

System.out.println("TRUE");
return true;
```

I really don't know how to sort it out.

**EDIT:**

the program print both "FALSE" and then "TRUE"

**EDIT:**

```
public boolean prosegui(int i, int j, int proseguiI, int proseguiJ, int contChar)
{
    if (contChar < this.parola.length() - 1)
    {
        int direzioneI=proseguiI-i;
        int direzioneJ=proseguiJ-j; 
        i=proseguiI+direzioneI;
        j=proseguiJ+direzioneJ;

        int cont;
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(this.results);

        cont=0;

        char[][] matrice = new char[this.lung][this.lung];

        while (st.hasMoreTokens())
        {
             matrice[cont]=st.nextElement().toString().toCharArray();
             cont++;
        }

        if(this.parola.charAt(contChar+1)==matrice[i][j]){

        prosegui(proseguiI,proseguiJ,i,j,contChar+1);
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("FALSE");
        return false;
    }
}

System.out.println("TRUE");
return true;
}
```

Comment: You should include your method declaration in the question.

Comment: and a case for which it fails

Comment: *return false doesn't return the value "false" as it should* => it certainly does. The only possible reason: that line does not get executed.

Comment: seems fine to me. are you sure the `else` branch is executed?

Comment: have you tried debugging it?

Comment: I have another method calling this one. I have to give in Input a word and it should find it in a matrix. It works for most of the words, but for certain as "CRIMINE", "NOIA" and "TRENO" it doesn't.

Comment: That is what we are saying but a debug point both in if and else statement.Then you will know whether the execution is going in else loop.

Comment: @vikiiii if-else isn't a loop, its a conditional statement

Comment: what is `prosegui(proseguiI,proseguiJ,i,j,contChar+1);` , to me it looks like, first time your inner if is true and this function is called where false is returned, then control comes back to the calling area and it returns true. But thats all a guess until you show what is `prosegui(proseguiI,proseguiJ,i,j,contChar+1);`

Comment: It does go inside the else loop and then just execute the following code.

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR Thanks for correcting me.I wil take care from next time.

Comment: @AlessandroCifani, I suggest you to write your code in english, to get a better support online, to share it with non-italians easily, etc. BTW, I don't get exactly what are you doing, but you may want to take a look at `HashMap<Character,List<Character>>`s instead of `char[][]`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this code is in the prosegui method, then when it calls itself here:

```
prosegui(proseguiI,proseguiJ,i,j,contChar+1);
```

The true/false returned by this call is never used.

Comment: The false is used it the char doesn't match, the true will be used when contChar gets equals to parola.length(), am I wrong?

Comment: thanks, I got the error, I simply added 
if(prosegui(proseguiI,proseguiJ,i,j,contChar+1)==false){
   return false;
}

Comment: Wouldn't `return prosegui(proseguiI,proseguiJ,i,j,contChar+1)` be simpler and do what you want?

Answer (score 2):

your function cannot return false when entering prosegui(...) recursivly, because you don't check the result of your recursive call, it will always return true.

Answer (score 2):

First time through, `this.parola.charAt(contChar+1)==matrice[i][j]` is true. This means that `prosegui` is called again with a different input (`prosegui(proseguiI,proseguiJ,i,j,contChar+1)`).

This time through `this.parola.charAt(contChar+1)==matrice[i][j]` is false. This means that "FALSE" will be printed, and `false` will be returned.

Now we are back at the call to `prosegui(proseguiI,proseguiJ,i,j,contChar+1)`. If we step forward from here, "TRUE" is printed and `true` is returned.

That's my theory anyway! Hope that helps.